# Call Center - Open CTI auth

Tags: api, authentication, opencti, call-center

I'm new to call center so maybe this is a basic question or not very well explained.

We have a third party company that needs to use the Open CTI API and connect there System to Salesforce.

I gave them all Salesforce Links for using the openCTI library.

What I couldn't understand and didn't find a link that explains it - Is how they need to make the Authentication.

How they use the code that they wrote with the openCTI library and connect to SF?

Should I use Auth 2.0 (connected App?) (I opened a user for them)

I saw that SF recommended using Canvas for auth...
But it not working for lightning experience.

In SF doc I found the script including:

```
 <script src="myDomain/support/api/48.0/lightning/opencti_min.js"></script>
```

where I'm supose to open the Auth so they could do there change?

What should I give them in order to make the connection to work

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long research about it,
I found out that we do not make any auth.

We should give the "myDomain" as the URL of the right environment we want to work on

```
 <script src="myDomain/support/api/48.0/lightning/opencti_min.js"></script>
```

and we should import XML to the call center FROM :

> Setup -> Call Center -> Import

The XML should be sent from the third party with all the details as explained here :

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cti_admin_cctemplatesample.htm&type=5

And we need to import that file to the Call center.

The Auth is defined inside the XML in "GeneralInfo" section. The third-party should supply the Adapter URL with more information.

After that, the connection is done automatically - since the methods from the OpenCTI JS library making behind the scenes API Calls to the Call Center Standard API.

Hope for someone to give more detailed information about it, and\or fix me if something is not said right.

Thanks.